# Issue with C, program prints values that aren't supposed to print

Tags: c

I've been trying to find an issue with this code for a few days but I still can't find it. The main problem here is that, when printing the values of each node, it tries to print an extra node and makes up new values.

The code works the following way, for example: I put numbers 10,11,15 and if the sum of all three numbers of the node is more than 20 then it adds the double before so the result would be: 20,22,30 || 10,11,15.

Every time I try to execute this code in Visual Studio Code the program prints:
20,22,30 || 10,11,15 || 0,26345856,301989906. As you can see, the program tries to print another node that doesn't exist so it makes up values. I've tried on some online compilers and this isn't a problem, so what I would like to know is if there is any error in my code or if it's the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list{
    int num;
    int num1;
    int num3;
    struct list *next;
}node;


void create (node *p){
    printf("Input first number: ");
    scanf("%d",&p->num);
    if (p->num==0)
        p->next=NULL;
    else{
        printf("Input second number: ");
        scanf("%d",&p->num1);
        printf("Input third number: ");
        scanf("%d",&p->num3);
        p->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        create (p->next);
    }
}

void show (node *p){
    if (p->next !=NULL){
        printf ("\n%d",p->num);
        printf ("\n%d",p->num1);
        printf ("\n%d",p->num3);
        show (p->next);
    }
}

node* add(node *p){
    node *aux;
    if((p->num+p->num1+p->num3)>20){
        aux=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        aux->num=p->num*2;
        aux->num1=p->num1*2;
        aux->num3=p->num3*2;
        aux->next=p;
        p=aux;
    }
    return p;
}

void add2 (node *p){
    node *aux=NULL;
    while(p->next!=NULL){
        if((p->next->num +p->next->num1+ p->next->num3)>20){
            aux=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            aux->num=p->next->num*2;  
            aux->num1=p->next->num1*2;
            aux->num3=p->next->num3*2;
            aux->next=p->next; 
            p->next=aux;
            p=p->next;
        }
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    node *prin=NULL;
    prin=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    create(prin);
    printf("Input numbers were: ");
    show (prin);
    prin=add(prin);
    add2(prin->next); 
    printf("\nList with added nodes: ");
    show(prin);
}
```

Comment: If you're asking on Stack Overflow, the problem is in your code.  You can safely assume that the compiler is perfect.  It's not quite true, but if you're asking the question, it is extremely unlikely to be the wrong assumption.

Comment: True, but under GCC, the output list is ```20 22 30 10 11 15```, exactly what the OP expected, so this question will go to someone who uses VS Code.

Comment: Exactly what input are you providing?  If it's only `10 11 15` then the recursive call to `create` will try to read more numbers, and `scanf` will fail, but you don't check its return value.  Add proper error handling to your `scanf` calls and then see where you are.

Comment: That's a weird null check, `if (p->next)` would suffice.

Comment: Hint: to make the bug reproducible on all platforms, try initializing `p->num1` and `p->num3` to fairly large positive values, like 100, in the `p->num == 0` branch of the `if` in `create()`.  Your program currently reads their uninitialized values so it may behave differently on different platforms, depending on what garbage is in those memory locations.

Comment: Nate I didn't understand what should I check. What is an error handling?

Comment: `scanf` has a return value which indicates whether an error occurred.  You need to test this return value and do something useful if an error happened.

Comment: Having compiled the code, both the original (with slightly relaxed compilation options from my normal ones) and a modified version which prints newlines at the end of lines, not before the start of a line, and prints 3 numbers on a single line, I _do_ get the expected behaviour, with both one set of three numbers and with several sets of three numbers. I also created a `malloc()` wrapper to set the allocated space to all bytes 0xFF; it worked correctly. I used debugging options on malloc too — still no trouble. So, although it is unusual, it does look like it might be a problem in VS Code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Try setting the allocated space to 0x22 instead... ;-)  And I think the input to reproduce is `10 11 15 0`.

Comment: Nate I changed the if statement to p->num == 100 and now the bug appears in the online compiler but I still don't know what is causing it

Comment: Make yourself a diagram of your list nodes after `add` completes.  Then single-step through `add2` and watch what is happening.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Curious!  Very Curious, Indeed!  On an antique RHEL 5 Linux machine (x86_64) with a home-built GCC 10.1.0 and Valgrind, with the filler set to `'\x22'` (equivalent to 0x22), I do indeed get the spurious entry printed, though Valgrind only complains about leaked memory, not any other memory abuse.  With the filler set to `'\xFF'`, I don't get the spurious entry printed.  On a RHEL 7.4 machine (GCC 4.8.5), I get similar behaviour; 0x22 shows the problem, 0xFF does not.  I'll need to think about "why" because I've not spotted the reason yet.

Comment: It has to do with whether the uninitialized fields sum to more than 20...

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yeah, putting printing before the `if((p->next->num +p->next->num1+ p->next->num3)>20){` condition in `add2()` shows that the code is looking at uninitialized data — hence undefined behaviour. Setting everything to 0xFF made those values -1 so the sum wasn't big enough; setting everything to 0x22 made those values 1 x 0 and 2 x 572662306 (0x22222222), so the sum was large enough (but not too large). So the program is exhibiting undefined behaviour — accessing uninitialized data.  The code leaks 4 memory allocations, in part because there's a pre-emptive memory allocation.  Grrr!

Comment: @NateEldredge: When I remove my malloc wrapper, of course, Valgrind goes bananas about using uninitialized values, and conditional jumps depending on uninitialized values.  Sometimes, wrappers are counter-productive — at least when working on a machine with Valgrind available (a problem on my Mac; Valgrind is not available there at the moment).  It isn't a problem in Visual Studio Code — as I originally stated.

Comment: So my code is trying to generate a new node with values that don't exist? Also I did myself a diagram and it should work fine but it doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The reason why setting the data to `0xFF` doesn't reproduce the error is that `0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming 32-bit integers) is a **negative** number, so the sum of `num1 + num3` will be less than 20. (See my answer - you may find it helpful.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry - I missed one of your comments, where you had already figured it out.

Comment: NP, @AdrianMole — I'm away from my computer and can't assemble an answer while walking a dog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *always* creating a 'dummy' node at the foot of your list. For example, if you enter `0` as the very first input, you will have a single-entry list where only the `num` (set to that `0`) and `next` (set to `NULL`) members are initialized. The `num1` and `num3` fields are left uninitialized by the `create` function. Likewise if, as in your given test case, you enter (and initialize) actual values for those last two fields, you will *still* have created a new 'foot' node in the next call to `create`.

As it happens, on your system, these uninitialized data fields have 'random' values that, together, add up to more than 20. (This is perfectly allowable by the C standard, but some compilers and/or platforms will, by default, set that uninitialized data to zero.)

Thus, in your call to the `add` function, the `if` test condition in:

```c
    if ((p->num + p->num1 + p->num3) > 20) {
        //...
```

will evaluate to `TRUE` and a new node will be added, with `num1` and `num3` having values twice that of the original 'random' values.

To fix the problem, set the `num1` and `num3` fields to zero (or some other small/negative numbers) in your `create` function, when the 'sentinel zero' end-of-input mark is entered for the `num` field:

```c
void create(node* p)
{
    printf("Input first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->num);
    if (p->num == 0) {
        p->next = NULL;
        p->num1 = 0; // You MUST ensure that the sum of these two numbers
        p->num3 = 0; // is LESS THAN 20 ... or a new node will be created
    }
    else {
        printf("Input second number: ");
        scanf("%d", &p->num1);
        printf("Input third number: ");
        scanf("%d", &p->num3);
        p->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        create(p->next);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** To see how this 'bug' is happening, try just setting the `num1` field to a specific number (say, 42) and leaving `num3` uninitialized. Then, only one of the 'made up' values will be unexplained - the other one will be twice what you have specified (so, 84). This would make a good exercise, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian! Now I understood what is happening and how to fix it.